# Image map not working in Internet Explorer 10

Tags: html, image, dictionary, internet-explorer-10

```
<img src="images/imagemap.png" width="600" height="100" border="0" usemap="#map" />

<map name="map">
<!-- #$-:Image map file created by GIMP Image Map plug-in -->
<!-- #$-:GIMP Image Map plug-in by Maurits Rijk -->
<!-- #$-:Please do not edit lines starting with "#$" -->
<!-- #$VERSION:2.3 -->
<!-- #$AUTHOR:Eric -->
<area shape="rect" coords="2,2,98,97"  onclick="scrollto1()" style="cursor: pointer;"     />
<area shape="rect" coords="102,3,202,95"  onclick="scrollto2()"  style="cursor:     pointer;" />
<area shape="rect" coords="208,3,307,95"  onclick="scrollto3()"  style="cursor: pointer;"/>
<area shape="rect" coords="315,5,409,98"  onclick="scrollto4()"  style="cursor: pointer;"/>
<area shape="rect" coords="413,6,502,97"  onclick="scrollto5()"  style="cursor: pointer;"/>
<area shape="rect" coords="507,4,597,97"  onclick="scrollto6()"  style="cursor: pointer;"/>
</map>
```

The image map is clickable in all browsers except Internet Explorer 10. I am wondering if there is some way to get things working in Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your code, its working now :)

you do not have the area self closing, and you were missing `href="#"` and style is not required at all :)

check the fiddle in case you want to check

```
Link : http://jsfiddle.net/MarmeeK/bD4s7/

<img src="http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/30600000/Template-800-x-100-pippy-and-jezzis-world-of-purdy-mindedness-30664157-800-100.jpg" width="600" height="100" border="0" usemap="#maps" alt="" />

<map name="maps">

<area shape="rect" coords="2,2,98,97"  onclick="scrollto1()" style="cursor: pointer;"     >
<area shape="rect" coords="102,3,202,95" href="#" >
<area shape="rect" coords="208,3,307,95" href="#" >
<area shape="rect" coords="315,5,409,98" href="#" >
<area shape="rect" coords="413,6,502,97" href="#" >
<area shape="rect" coords="507,4,597,97" href="#" onclick="javascript:alert('hi');" >
</map>
```